# Webapplication displays different images in a network

Tags: networking, cache, azure, web-application

I agree that this question should be asked in stackoverflow.com and not here. I'm asking it here because it is related to networks and configuration.

I've web application and it has some static images in some pages. Those images are stored in a folder and path given in the html file. This application is hosted in Microsoft Azure in Australia region. A user is accessing from middle east. We have updated some static images and those images are being shown properly in australia and elsewhere but in the middle east users still see old images in the application.

We have tried different browsers and machines but it is the same issue. We cleared cache did everything at client machine.

I'm guessing this issue might be at network level, something like caching these images at the user company network or ISP. Or it might be issue with azure data centers where they might be caching it at a regional data center.

These are my wild guesses and they might be completely wrong assumptions. I would like to hear from experts about this issue.